# Alias to set default CLI options on PowerShell

Tags: powershell, command-line-arguments, alias

I want to use `new-alias` or `set-alias` aliases to set `--includeuser` as a default switch for `get-process` cmdlet.

I do:

```
new-alias get-process 'get-process -includeuser'
```

but I get the following error on executing `get-process`:

> get-process : The term 'get-process -includeuser $*' is not recognized
>   as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
>   Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that
>   the path is correct and try again.

Please help me with that.

---

For comparison `cmd.exe` aliaseses can be set with `doskey` as follows:

```
doskey task=tasklist
```

`$*` can be used if there's input arguments to the command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aliases in PowerShell don't accept arguments. The usual workaround is to define a short function; e.g.:

```
function task { tasklist $args }
```

The `$args` variable would be the rough equivalent to `$*` in `doskey`.

In PowerShell v3 and later, you can also use the built-in `$PSDefaultParameterValues` variable (a hashtable) to assign default parameter values to cmdlets. For example:

```
$PSDefaultParameterValues.Add("Get-Process:IncludeUserName",$true)
```

This would specify that the `Get-Process` cmdlet uses `-IncludeUserName` as a default.

The hashtable key is the cmdlet name, the `:` character and the parameter name (without leading `-`), and the hashtable value is the value for the parameter.